# how to compile flex modules?

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, swc, fdt

I'm trying to migrate from flash builder to eclipse FDT in order to have one IDE for everything. the problem is that I have a lot of flex modules in my projects and it seems that FDT doesn't have native support for flex modules.

how can I add a flex module configuration ?

should I just compile them as regular Flex Application ?
how can I add external resources (swc files) to that flex module compilation ?

thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "flex module"? You can add SWCs by right-clicking your project and selecting `Properties -> FDT Build Path -> Library`.

Comment: I mean that I have a flex project that contains several mxml files that start with an <mx:module tag instead of an <s:Application tag. and I want each module to be compiled as an swf file in the bin directory of the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that FDT does not support compiling Flex modules the way Flash Builder does.  It has already been [requested as a feature](http://bugs.powerflasher.com/jira/browse/FDT-1099?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3achangehistory-tabpanel).

So you're stuck with two options: Use Ant (or Maven, but from what I've read, Maven is not all that good with modules, either), or set up individual run configurations for each of the modules and link them directly within FDT via the "Launcher Chain" tab in the run configurations panel.